# Why is next lint different from build lint in Next.js

Tags: next.js, eslint

When I use `npx next lint`, it no error was detected,but when i use `npm run build`, it checked out the mistake.

Is there any difference in running lint between the two

[image]

This is my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
"extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "next"
],
"rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
}
```

}

This is my `package.json`

```
{
"name": "nextjs-blog",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"license": "MIT",
"description": "blog",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
},
```

I want to be able to check for errors when I run `npx next lint`

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Edit your question to remove the images and show the text instead.

Comment: share your *package.json*